# how to convert rows to columns using sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2008

Pls see the below query

```
 select D.emp_id, E.emp_name, A.proj_code, B.proj_name, A.activity_code, C.activity_name,
CONVERT(CHAR(4), A.effort_date, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), A.effort_date, 120) as Month, A.effort_hours
from timesheet_activity A left join
project_master B on A.proj_code = B.proj_code
left join activity_master C on A.activity_code = C.activity_code
left join timesheet D on A.timesheet_id = D.timesheet_id
left join employee_master E on D.emp_id = E.emp_id
WHERE B.proj_name IN ('Sales Support') and (A.effort_date BETWEEN (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(date, '30-06-2014', 105), 23))  AND (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(date, '02-07-2014', 105), 23)))
```

The result will be like this.

[image]

Now what I want to show is as below.

```
emp_id  emp_name  proj_code  activity_code  activity_name Jun 2014  Jul 2014
101257  Chris      1001       9001           Test          1.5         1
```

I want to make the months as columns and show efforts hours for the same.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated

Comment: Look for PIVOT, there are tons of samples in SO and the web

Comment: @SJD, Use pivot

Answer (score 1):

`WITH ABC 
AS
( 
paste your query to get that result here
)
Select * FROM ABC
PIVOT (MAX(effort_hours) for Month in ([Jun 2014],[Jul 2014])) as MaxHrs`

You could change the function `MAX` to any math function you want for selecting condition